# spread operator - for object, not recognizing its objects name

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am passing down the props `editing`, `selectedPost` from parent component to child component, to use it to set the state in child component.

I do this to check if the previous `editing`, `selectedPost` is different from newly passed down props, when the child component is being re-rendered.

I check this difference in my `useEffect` state, to validate if the value of the current form(post) needs to be updated with the newest value or not.

But I wonder if the logic is faulty, since child component's `prevEditing` and `prevSelectedPost` will always update its value same as the passed down props value?

```
export default function FeedEdit({editing, selectedPost){

  const [ prevEditing, setPrevEditing ] = useState(editing)
  const [ prevSelectedPost, setPrevSelectedPost ] = useState(selectedPost)

    useEffect(() => {
    if (
      editing &&
      //check if the logic here is correct
      prevEditing !== editing &&
      prevSelectedPost !== selectedPost
    ) {
      const updatedPostForm = {
        title: {
          // ...title,
          value: selectedPost.title,
          valid: true
        },
        image: {
          // ...image,
          value: selectedPost.imagePath,
          valid: true
        },
        content: {
          // ...content,
          value: selectedPost.content,
          valid: true
        }
      }
      setPostForm(updatedPostForm)
      setFormIsValid(true)
    }
  }, [])

}
```

Comment: missing effect dependencies `}, [editing, selectedPost])` ??

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to add these `editing` and `selectedPost` into the dependency list. If any of these dependency gets updated, `useEffects` will kick in. Previously since the dependency was blank, `useEffect` was not triggering.

```
const [ prevEditing, setPrevEditing ] = useState(editing)
const [ prevSelectedPost, setPrevSelectedPost ] = useState(selectedPost)

    useEffect(() => {


  const updatedPostForm = {
    title: {
      // ...title,
      value: selectedPost.title,
      valid: true
    },
    image: {
      // ...image,
      value: selectedPost.imagePath,
      valid: true
    },
    content: {
      // ...content,
      value: selectedPost.content,
      valid: true
    }
  }
  setPostForm(updatedPostForm)


    setFormIsValid(true)

   }, [editing, selectedPost])
```